# MobileFirst 7.1 ( Error:"Access to server disabled")

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to login into add, we have a adapter for login, when i click login. I get "ACCESS TO SERVER DISABLE" ERROR.

Here is the log

018-10-12 21:34:21.324881+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkDetector'] took '13.218018' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2018-10-12 21:34:22.428954+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086763] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
2018-10-12 21:34:22.430047+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086763] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
2018-10-12 21:34:22.442243+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1087344] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth
2018-10-12 21:34:22.444255+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] +[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.ibm.cio.be.na.efridays
2018-10-12 21:34:22.447221+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] [ERROR] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager getKeyChainKeyBits:isCertificate:] in WLCertManager.m:180 :: getting keychain bits --> Failed
2018-10-12 21:34:22.452254+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1087344] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
2018-10-12 21:34:22.454633+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086763] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/api/efridaysapp/iphone/init]
2018-10-12 21:34:22.455629+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:169 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2017/07/20 10:29:34
2018-10-12 21:34:22.469228+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '10.920166' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2018-10-12 21:34:22.481627+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1087376] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://xxxx/xxx/apps/services/api/efridaysapp/iphone/init
2018-10-12 21:34:22.489005+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1087376] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://xxxx/xxx/apps/services/api/efridaysapp/iphone/init
2018-10-12 21:34:23.327292+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
2018-10-12 21:34:23.329749+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 403
2018-10-12 21:34:23.331777+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : Request failed: forbidden (403)
2018-10-12 21:34:23.415575+0530 efridaysapp[97097:1086487] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '76.531738' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

Comment: 1) What is your exact MFP server version and build?
2) What is the status of the application in the server? Is it disabled ( Remote Disable) or marked as 'LOST' or 'STOLEN'?
3) Is application authenticity enabled?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The MobileFirst version is 7.1 and the application status is active. It is not disabled.

Comment: Do you have app authenticity enabled? Also, can you capture network traffic between client and server?

Comment: app authenticity is set to none